# JOI validation for a string with json as a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

i am trying to validate the string using the JOI package available in npm, i checked [this](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.6.0#string) documentation which has many useful string formats e.g. date, IP, base64 but i need to validate the following JSON which contains a stringified JSON as a value, and there is no example in the documentation for such case

```
{
    "id": 232,
    "name": "Trojan Horse",
    "file": "download.exe",
    "infected": true, 
    "engines": "['Norton', 'AVG', 'NOD32']"
}
```

So for example what if i want to check `engines` have valid JSON value and have at-least one engine defined if `infected` key is set to `true`

The following schema works only if the `engines` value is written as parsed JSON

```
Joi.object().keys({
    id: Joi.number().required(),
    name: Joi.string().min(5).required(),
    file: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
    infected: Joi.boolean().required(),
    engines: Joi.array().when('infected', {
        is: Joi.exists().valid(true),
        then: Joi.min(1).required()
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a custom JOI validator by extending the array validator of the JOI package and using that custom validator for the engines property.

```
const custom = Joi.extend({
type: 'array',
base: Joi.array(),
coerce: {
      from: 'string',
      method(value, helpers) {

          if (typeof value !== 'string' ||
              value[0] !== '[' && !/^\s*\[/.test(value)) {

              return;
          }

          try {
            return { value: JSON.parse(value) };
          }
          catch (ignoreErr) { }
      }
  }
});

const schema = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.number().required(),
  name: Joi.string().min(5).required(),
  file: Joi.string().min(3).required(),
  infected: Joi.boolean().required(),
  engines: custom.array().when('infected', {
      is: true,
      then: custom.array().min(1).required()
  })
})

const validateTest = async (joiSchema,  testObject) => {
  try {
    const value = await joiSchema.validateAsync(testObject);
    console.log(value);
}
catch (err) { 
  console.error(err)
 }
};

validateTest(schema, {
  "id": 232,
  "name": "Trojan Horse",
  "file": "download.exe",
  "infected": true, 
  "engines": `["Norton", "AVG", "NOD32"]`
})
```

You can see more examples like that [here](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/test/extend.js#L1490)

Comment: This is just for update, i noticed after lot of experiments that new version of Joi automatically process the stringified objects or arrays and validates all rules defined as is, no need to write custom validator or extend previous Joi type

Comment: This is just for update, i noticed after lot of experiments that new version of Joi automatically process the stringified objects or arrays and validates all rules defined as is, no need to write custom validator or extend previous Joi type